# Why can I not type cast Interface into its concrete implementation?

Tags: c#, interface, casting

Here is a very trivial problem that seems rather annoying due to my lack of experience but, why can I not do something like this:

```
 public interface INetworkMessage { ... }
 public class NetworkDataMessage : INetworkMessage { ... }

 public void ParseMessage (INetworkMessage message)
 {
     Type concreteMessageType = message.GetType();
     var concreteMessageInstance = message as concreteMessageType;
     ...
     // Now in theory I could work with a concrete type?
 }
```

Comment: You *can*, but in general you *shouldn't*.  If you have to do that then it's usually a sign that there's something wrong with your design.  Attempting to do so carries risks if the backing type isn't the type you expect.

Comment: Because `INetworkMessage` is not necessarily a `NetworkDataMessage`, it can be any implementation of it, so how do you know which concrete type to cast to?

Comment: @RonBeyer but doesn't GetType() return the exact concrete type?

Comment: @David how would I then for example go about passing any message type that implements a certain interface into a method?

Comment: No, `GetType` returns the `Type` of the concrete type, as in its a `Type` object, not something you can cast. It would be the same as `message as typeof(message)`, which doesn't make any sense. GetType returns a Type, not the type of the object. Its difficult to explain, but it doesn't work like you are thinking. `as` works at compile time, not run time.

Comment: @eYe: The exact way you're doing it now, but having the method accept a parameter of the interface type.  The method should perform operations on that interface, not on only one specific implementing type.

Comment: @David look at the code again, he's trying to get the type using `GetType` then using `as` to cast it to a variable. This code will not compile. Its not pseudo-code, `concreteMessageType` is a variable.

Comment: @RonBeyer: Ah, I hadn't noticed that.  True, this can't be done in this manner then.  But my point remains that it *shouldn't* be done to begin with.

Comment: It boils down to if you need it as a concrete type, define the method with the desired concrete type to begin with.

Comment: @David Could you provide a brief example please?

Comment: @eYe: An example of what, exactly?  You need to think of the architecture of your system and determine what this method needs to do and how it fits into your overall system.  If the method needs an instance of `NetworkDataMessage`, then accept a parameter of that type.  If it needs an instance of `INetworkMessage`, then accept a parameter of that type.  What you're asking in the question is addressing a symptom of a problem you shouldn't have in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question: you can directly cast the object using a cast operation and the compile-time type name:

```
var concreteMessageInstance = (NetworkDataMessage)message; //may throw InvalidCastException for different implementation of INetworkMessage
```

Or

```
var concreteMessageInstance = message as NetworkDataMessage;
if(concreteMessageInstance != null) { /* ... */ }
```

However: you should rethink your design if you need a concrete implementation from an interface. The whole idea of the interface is that the details don't matter - maybe the thing you're trying to do on the concrete type should be moved into the interface? Or maybe you should use the concrete type directly instead and skip out on the interface? Both are design decisions you should consider.

If you want to be able to cast to any concrete implementation of the interface dynamically and invoke some operation, then you DEFINITELY should move the operation from the concrete type to the interface. The cast just adds extra overhead and a well-designed application would have such an operation in the interface definition from the start.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use `as` to cast to a type which you specify at compile time (either directly or via generics). Your code won't compile.

Since you don't know at compile time what `concreteMessageType` is, you also can't use `concreteMessageInstance` (if such a cast were possible), since the methods/properties/fields/etc. you would use need to be known by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up following David's suggestion in my own way:

```
public void ParseMessage<T> (INetworkMessage message) where T : INetworkMessage
 {
   // So now I can do
   var concreteInstance = (T)message;
}
```

Comment: But how does that help you? You can't really do anything more by casting to T.